# textbox focus check

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a win app form with 3 text boxes and buttons as dial pad (it's a touchscreen app)...

When a dial pad button is pressed I want to check which one of these 3 text boxes has focus, and append text to it.

Something like:

```
if (tbx1.Focused == true)
{
   tbx1.Text += "0";
}
else if (tbx2.Focused == true)
{
   tbx2.Text += "0";
}
else
{
   tbx3.Text += "0";
}
```

But this doesn't work... It appends text to tbx3 all the time.
Any suggestions?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem arises when you click the button, the button will gain focus and not any of your textboxes.

What you can do is subscribe to the [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx) event and remember what textbox had the focus last.

Something like:

```
private TextBox lastFocused;
private void load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    foreach (TextBox box in new TextBox[] { txtBox1, txtBox2, txtBox3 }){
        box.LostFocus += textBoxFocusLost;
    }
}

private void textBoxFocusLost(object sender, EventArgs e){
    lastFocused = (TextBox)sender;
}
```

Comment: Completely forgot about losing focus!! Your first sentence was more than enough. Thanks.